# Need to remove null values

Tags: sql, null, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table called **TEST** and data stored like this

```
ID        In                        Out     
1         2016-06-24 06:54:00       NULL        
1         NULL                     2016-06-24 17:09:00  
1         2016-06-25 06:54:00   NULL 
1         NULL                     2016-06-25 17:09:00
```

I am expecting the output as

```
ID        In                        Out 
1         2016-06-24 06:54:00       2016-06-24 17:09:00 
1         2016-06-25 06:54:00       2016-06-25 17:09:00
```

I tried

```
select coalesce (In,Out) from test
where ID=1
```

But it Gives me

```
In

2016-06-24 06:54:00
```

Is there any function which can help, how can we achieve that

Comment: Is it possible to have `In` and `Out` without `NULL`

Comment: there could you be multiple entries for the same day as well ? If No, then why do you want to have seprate entries for in and out ?

Comment: There will be millions entry bt there ID will be different

Comment: @RedDevil check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this one  ?

```
SELECT ID,MAX(IN) AS IN ,MAX(OUT) AS OUT from test group by ID
```

**==UPDATE==**

I would suggest to re-design your table and **UPDATE** `in` and `out` columns with current date time instead of inserting new rows.

Comment: I already tried and it will give only 1 record, If i have 10 entries for ID= 1 it will select only the max in and out time

Comment: why do you have 10 entries ?? could you also put this in your question for better clarity. What have you tried and what is your test cases.. you need to show us first.

Comment: I suppose that there can only be one in and out entry each per ID *and date*. If this is the case you'll simply have to add `, convert(date, coalesce(in,out))` at the end of your query. (And an additional `order by` clause would make the results more readable.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ravi, don't `Insert` a new row when there is a `Out` time. `Update` the record with `Out` time.

But with your current table structure to achieve the result you can do something like this

```
;with cte as
(
select *,
       ((row_number() over(partition by [ID] order by coalesce([In],[Out]))-1)/2)+1 as grp 
from Yourtable
)
select Id,min([In]),max([Out])
from cte
group by Id,grp
```

**Note :** The above code considers there will be always two entries for a `day` per `ID`